# What does runtests.jl do in Julia?

Tags: julia, julia-pkg

I have seen that many Julia projects seem to include a file in the test folder called "runtests.jl". Is there something significant about that file name or can I have my testing file called whatever I want?

Comment: It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.234024286.1949022841.1631233456-1690002512.1626695629&_gac=1.118873467.1631243013.Cj0KCQjw4eaJBhDMARIsANhrQAAr9FjQp8hjie7s2gkeOGuC4H9izpdqrerj3VpLe7e9l0cnTHr_1bsaAmPYEALw_wcB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in the [package manager docs](https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/dev/creating-packages/#Adding-tests-to-the-package), when you run `test` in the package manager while you have a particular package activated, it will default to looking for a `runtests.jl` file. From the docs, it does not appear there is a way to override this naming convention so it should be assumed the entry point for you unit tests should be the `runtests.jl` file.